# Terraform AWS How use Security Group's port another that 22 for SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group

I want using another SG's port for SSH, not 22, but i get error.
For example:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "ws_sg" {
    name = "WS SG"
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.ws_net.id}"
    tags = {
      "Name" = "WS SG"
    }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "inbound_ssh" {
    from_port = 28
    protocol = "TCP"
    security_group_id = aws_security_group.ws_sg.id
    to_port = 22
    type = "ingress"
    cidr_blocks = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ]
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress" {
    from_port = 0
    protocol = "all"
    security_group_id = aws_security_group.ws_sg.id
    to_port = 0
    type = "egress"
    cidr_blocks = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ]
}
```

How fix it?

P.S. Maybee, this happing because i have free account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up your ports. Instead of

```
   from_port = 28
   to_port = 22
```

it should be:

```
   from_port = 22
   to_port = 28
```

Answer (score 0):

I some hastened. Not working

I tried connect PuTTY to port 28 and i got:
Network error: Connection refused

If i change SG's inbounds for SSH 22, then connect to port 22 without problem.
But if i change 22-28, that's all guys )

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).